# Kendo UI Grid cell coloring in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In Kendo UI Grid. I want to change the backround of the cell, which is having the value -111, -222 and IV , IT.

help me to write the jquery for changing backround color.

my code:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("gridexcel")
    .Events(events => events.DataBound(@<text>coloring()</text>))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
     columns.Bound(c => c.ExcelId).Title("Id").Visible(false);
     columns.Bound(c => c.status).Title("Status").Width(100);
     columns.Bound(c => c.report_date).Title("Report Date");
     columns.Bound(c => c.code).Width(50);
 //and additional columns from 1 to 50
    }


    var coloring = function () {
    var grid = $("#gridexcel").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.tbody
    .find(":contains('-111')")
    .closest("td")
    .css("background", "red");
    grid.tbody
    .find(":contains('-222')")
    .closest("tr")
    .css("background", "red");

    grid.tbody
    .find(":contains('IV')")
    .closest("tr")
    .css("background", "green");

    grid.tbody
    .find(":contains('IT')")
    .closest("tr")
    .css("background", "red");
    };
```

Comment: For which column do you wish to change the bg-color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than selecting all the values, you just need to add single line code as below:

```
$('td').each(function(){if($(this).text()=='-111'){$(this).addClass('red')}});
```

Please see a working demo:
**[Kendo Grid Changing Cell Color](http://jsfiddle.net/D_Learning/G5s52/2/)**